# Get data url from an image url with NodeJS

Tags: node.js

I am trying to get the data url within nodejs by supplying an image url and being returned the url. I want it to be done with promises and have been struggling... mainly because I am doing this at 5am

An example of what I want returned is this:
`data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAMQAAORHHOVSKudfOulrSOp3WOyDZu6QdvCchPGolfO0o/XBs/fNwfjZ0frl3/zy7////wAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH5BAkAABAALAAAAAAQABAAAAVVICSOZGlCQAosJ6mu7fiyZeKqNKToQGDsM8hBADgUXoGAiqhSvp5QAnQKGIgUhwFUYLCVDFCrKUE1lBavAViFIDlTImbKC5Gm2hB0SlBCBMQiB0UjIQA7`

I need it to be able to take in a url input, fetch the image data, convert it and return it.

I am having no luck at all, anyone have some ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I love fixing issues instantly after asking for help! Here was my solution:
import request from "request";

```
import request from "request";

const extTypeMap = {
  'png': 'image/png',
  'jpg': 'image/jpeg',
  'jpeg': 'image/jpeg',
  'webp': 'image/webp'
};

export const getImageDataUri = async (url: string): Promise<string> => {
  try {
    const stream = request(url),
      buffer = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const chunks: Buffer[] = [];
        stream.on("data", (chunk) => chunks.push(chunk));
        stream.on("end", () => resolve(Buffer.concat(chunks)));
        stream.on("error", reject);
      }) as any,
      dataUri = `data:${extTypeMap[url.split(".").pop()] || "image/png"};base64,${buffer.toString("base64")}`;

    return dataUri;
  } catch {
    return "";
  }
}
```